# Using partial view updates asp.net ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Trying to display only one comment from the text box in the partial view.

To get some data you need the Session Controller:

```
private ConferenceContext context = new ConferenceContext();

        //
        // GET: /Session/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ConferenceContext context = new ConferenceContext();
            List<Session> sessions = context.Sessions.ToList();
            return View(sessions);
        }
//
        // GET: /Session/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            Session session = context.Sessions.Find(id);
            if (session == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(session);
        }
```

Details View in the Session Folder:

```
    @model Conference.Models.Session

<h3>
    @Model.Title
</h3>
<div>
    @Model.Abstract
</div>

@Html.Action("_GetForSession", "Comment", new { SessionID = Model.SessionID })
```

Then the CommentController, which is using the partial view _GetForSession to display the text from the Text Box:

```
ConferenceContext context = new ConferenceContext();
        public PartialViewResult _GetForSession(Int32 sessionID)
        {
            ViewBag.SessionID = sessionID;
            List<Comment> comments = context.Comments.Where(c => c.SessionID == sessionID).ToList();
            return PartialView("_GetForSession", comments);
        }

        [ChildActionOnly()]
        public PartialViewResult _CommentForm(Int32 sessionID)
        {
            Comment comment = new Comment() { SessionID = sessionID };
            return PartialView("_CommentForm", comment);
        }

        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
        public PartialViewResult _Submit(Comment comment)
        {
            context.Comments.Add(comment);
            context.SaveChanges();

            List<Comment> comments = context.Comments.Where(c => c.SessionID == comment.SessionID).ToList();
            ViewBag.SessionID = comment.SessionID;

            return PartialView("_GetForSession", comments);
        }
```

Here is the _GetForSession View from the Comment folder:

```
@model IEnumerable<Conference.Models.Comment>

<div id="comments">
    <ul>
        @foreach (var comment in Model)
        {
            <li>@comment.Content</li>
        }
    </ul>

    @using(Ajax.BeginForm("_Submit", "Comment", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "comments" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
        @Html.Action("_CommentForm", new { SessionID = ViewBag.SessionID })
    }
</div>
```

The _GetForSession gets its data from the _CommentForm in the Comment folder:

```
@model Conference.Models.Comment

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SessionID)

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Content)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Content)
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit Comment</button>
```

Now the main Context would be coming from ConferenceContext in the Models:

```
public class ConferenceContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Speaker> Speakers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

And the Context itself from the ConferenceContextInitializer:

```
public class ConferenceContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ConferenceContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ConferenceContext context)
        {
            context.Sessions.Add(
                new Session()
                {
                    Title = "Partial View",
                    Abstract = "View Within the Main",
                    Speaker = context.Speakers.Add(new Speaker()
                    {
                        Name = "John Smith",
                        EmailAddress = "johnsmith@nowhere.com"
                    })
                });
     context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

So, my question is can it be possible to display only one comment in the partial view not two?

Comment: do you ALWAYS want to display one comment or just make it an option?

Comment: At the moment if the comment being made it shows one comment from Models.Comment and another one is from System.Data in list of comments

Comment: public class Comment
    {
        public Int32 CommentID { get; set; }

        public String Content { get; set; }

        public Int32 SessionID { get; set; }

        public virtual Session Session { get; set; }
    }